# How to correctly measure the running time of an opencl program

Tags: opencl

When I used opencl to test the performance of the program, I encountered some doubts. The original intention of our experiment was to test the calculation time of the program, but there were some problems in the actual process. In the following code, timex uses the method of binding events to calculate the results. However, in the actual results, we found that (end_time - start_time) < time1+time2+time3 . We don't know why, and we're also curious how exactly we should calculate the running time of the task.

```
start_time = clock()
compute(){
    writeData();  // time1
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(); // time2
    readData(); //time3
    do_other();
}
end_time = clock()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you want to measure. If it is just for profiling, you could be interested in `time1`, `time2` and `time3` separately. If it is for measuring the performance of the `compute()`, you want to measure its entire runtime.

To measure time with nanosecond precision, use this clock:

```c
#include <chrono>
class Clock {
private:
    typedef chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;
    chrono::time_point<clock> t;
public:
    Clock() { start(); }
    void start() { t = clock::now(); }
    double stop() const { return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(clock::now()-t).count(); }
};
```

In your example, the issue with `(end_time-start_time) < time1+time2+time3` may have two possible reasons:

1. Your clock implementation is not accurate enough and it is just rounding error.
2. You didn't use `clFinish(queue);`. The OpenCL commands are only enqueued, but not executed right away. So `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel();` for example immediately returns, and if you measure time before and time after, you get practically 0. To wait until the Kernel really has been executed, you need to call `clFinish` afterards.

Example:

Measure `time1`, `time2` and `time3` separately:

```c
compute() {
    //clFinish(queue); // if there could still be stuff in the queue, finish it first
    Clock clock;
    clock.start();
    writeData(); // time1
    clFinish(queue);
    const double time1 = clock.stop(); // in seconds
    clock.start();
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(); // time2
    clFinish(queue);
    const double time2 = clock.stop(); // in seconds
    clock.start();
    readData(); //time3
    clFinish(queue);
    const double time3 = clock.stop(); // in seconds
    do_other();
    clFinish(queue); // don't forget to finish the queue!
}
```

To measure the entire execution time of `compute()`, you only need one `clFinish` at the end.

```c
compute() {
    //clFinish(queue); // if there could still be stuff in the queue, finish it first
    Clock clock;
    clock.start();
    writeData(); // time1
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(); // time2
    readData(); //time3
    do_other();
    clFinish(queue); // don't forget to finish the queue!
    const double time = clock.stop(); // in seconds
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! You have helped me with a lot of questions in the community. I found that although I noticed to wait for the event to complete, I was using the clWaitForEvents function in the code, and I planned to replace it with clFinish to calculate. Also, do you know how these two functions are directly different?

Comment: `clWaitForEvents` waits for one specific event to happen, for example when one specific kernel finishes. `clFinish` waits until everything in the queue has finished and the queue is completely empty. Consider marking my answer as correct answer / upvoting if this has helped you :)